# NMDS with ecological data containing many zeros in R - data transformations

Tags: r, multidimensional-scaling, vegan

I am trying to perform NMDS `metaMDs()` on mixed taxonomic data in R. My taxa data is organized with rows as observations and columns as different taxa. These data contain many zeros. I found that transforming my data using `decostand(method="total")` or `decostand(method="wisconsin")` causes my NMDS to throw a warning of a stress value of nearly zero. Are there any recommendations, other transformations, or other ordination techniques I can try to work with data like these? My environmental data that I am trying to fit to the NMDS result contains a mix of factor and numeric variables.

Comment: We need more information: how many observations? how many taxa? how many dimensions? The reason for the degenerate solution (stress nearly zero) is probably  one or some of these. Can you provide a reproducible example?